# Pytest: test only one instance of parametrized fixture

Tags: python, pytest

## Setting

Suppose I have `conftest.py` where I defined resources for tests

```
class ClassifyRequest:
    pass

class OCRRequest:
    pass

@pytest.fixture(params=[ClassifyRequest, OCRRequest])
def api_request(request):
    return request.param()  # return one of the request instances
```

Then, in `test_api.py` I use the parametrized fixture to test a service:

```
def test_service(api_request):
    response = send_request(api_request)
    assert response.ok()
```

All good, but then I want to test specialized fixture `api_request[ClassifyRequest]`:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixture("api_request[ClassifyRequest]")
def test_classification():
    # do something with the api_request fixture
```

## Question

*What is the way to specialize a parametrized fixture for a test function?* I have two ideas:

1. Just use a non-parametrized fixture. This inevitably leads to boilerplate code.
2. Remove explicit parametrization from the fixture decorator and use indirect parametrization like

   ```
   @pytest.mark.parametrize("response_class", ["classify", "ocr"])
   def test_api(api_request):
       # do smth
   ```

   Replacing class parameters with strings equals creating two sources of configuration. What if I want to add another parameter? Do I have to design a new string for it, as well as instantiate an object inside `api_request` fixture indirectly?
3. The same, except keep class parametrization and move classes outside `conftest.py` as pytest can't import names from that module with import statements.

### Additional info

pytest==6.0.1

Comment: Do you mean you have parametrized the tests with multiple values, but want to run with only a subset of them??

Comment: I parametrized the fixture, not the tests. Some tests run against all parametrized fixture instances, and some I want to run against only specific instance.

Comment: okay. so basically its a test filtering usecase you are looking for.. do u want it to be like, pass some parameters which points to what fixture values to skip??

Comment: I thinks so. Something as simple as passing `api_request[ClassifyRequest]` to the test function.

Answer (score 1):

If all your fixture does is instantiation, I'd opt for parametrizing the test, not the fixture. But, well, if you have to and **specialize** it manually anyway, you could simply add a wrapper to make the fixture callable:

```
import pytest
import types

class ClassifyRequest:
    def __init__(self):
        print("ClassifyRequest ctor")

class OCRRequest:
    def __init__(self):
        print("OCRRequest ctor")

def api_request_wrapper(request):
    return request.param()  # return one of the request instances

@pytest.fixture(params=[ClassifyRequest, OCRRequest])
def api_request(request):
    return api_request_wrapper(request)

def test_classification():
    request = types.SimpleNamespace()
    request.param = ClassifyRequest
    instance = api_request_wrapper(request)
```

Seems a bit hacky, though.

Comment: The problem is the tests themselves are in a different module, not in `conftest.py`. I can't import class names from `conftest.py` so as pytest sees them.

Comment: So, as you cannot import the type, you have to use a string then, right? Maybe it'd make sense to move them into a separate, common module?

Comment: Maybe a separate module, right. This even would rid me of necessity to put request classes into fixtures, provided that I can instantiate an object of request for every test function. However, the original question about pytest functionality remains. Can I specify fixture parameter for a specific test?

Comment: Without actually importing the types? So you want python to automagically bind strings to types? Doubt it but can't say for sure.

Comment: No-no, if I put request classes in a separate module, I am able to import them in `test_api.py`, no problem. Maybe pytest design is to aggregate resources into a parametrized fixture if and only if you plan to test all the resources together, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is to create test case filtering rules. The best place to do that is via the "pytest_collection_modifyitems" hook in Pytest.

This hook will be called once all the tests are collected from the path you give as input to Pytest.

You can put your logic in this hook.

Its always a best practice to associate an ID along with your parameters like below:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[ClassifyRequest, OCRRequest], 
                ids=['ClassifyRequest', 'OCRRequest'])
def api_request(request):
    return request.param()  # return one of the request instances
```

Once you have this, your testcase will be generated as test_classification[ClassifyRequest] and test_classification['OCRRequest']..

If you are running specific set of tests and want the filtering to apply on all the tests, then -k option itself will suffice.

But since here its only on a subset of tests you want to apply the rule, the hook definition can be in the module where the test is present.

Comment: To be honest, modifying test collection hook to deselect test items seems like introducing another source of control. If I would like to add another request class to test it in `test_api.py` with others and then some specialized test for this class only, I should modify this hook again. I don't want to introduce extra control sources.
Ideally, I'd like to declare a new resource once and maybe add it to the aggregate fixture without modifying any other code.

Comment: And yeah, thank you! This is an interesting insight.

Comment: Lets say you have some 'N' number of tests to run, and u dont want to run any test which is related to 'OCRRequest',you can always do -k 'not OCRRequest' in the pytest Invocation, that will do the default filtering out as i have mentioned.. That will be a simplest way to execute your tests with only a limited set of parameterised ones.

Comment: What if I want to run `test_service` with all the requests and `test_classification` with `ClassificationRequest` only and `test_ocr` with `OCRRequest`? Do I have to specify `-k test_service or test_classification[ClassificationRequest] or test_ocr[OCRRequest]`? Seems a hack to me as it requires to list all the scenarios I want to test. There's no common pattern between them, sadly.

Comment: True that.. difficult to maintain when u have too many of these conditions..

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** this is an preliminary conclusion, I created an [issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/7642) on pytest Github to see the community's opinion on this topic.

---

I think the cleanest way to implement the desired specialization is to move the request classes to a separate module and use `conftest.py` to declare **fixture functions only**. According to pytest [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixture-functions),

> If during implementing your tests you realize that you want to use a fixture function from multiple test files you can move it to a `conftest.py` file.

> If you want to make test data from files available to your tests, a good way to do this is by loading these data in a fixture for use by your tests.

This way I can import classes in test modules and parametrize the fixture indirectly through test functions. In my case request classes are very easy to instantiate, so there's no need for a separate fixture for each class, only the aggregate. But generally, it's ok to define a fixture for each resource and an aggregate parametrized fixture.

Answer (score 0):

You could also separate fixtures for `ClassifyRequest` and use it in your classification test **and** `api_request` fixture.

The assumption is that the instantiation of the requests are cheap. If they are expensive you could consider changing the scope of the fixtures.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def classify_request():
    return ClassifyRequest()  # return ClassifyRequest instance

@pytest.fixture
def ocr_request():
    return OCRRequest()  # return OCRRequest instance

@pytest.fixture(params=["classify", "ocr"])
def api_request(request, classify_request, ocr_request):
    # return one of the request instances
    if request.param == "classify":
         return classify_request
    elif request.param == "ocr":
         return ocr_request
    assert False
```

or else (this is a slight modification of your idea), whitelist the classes you want from `test_classification`

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[ClassifyRequest, OCRRequest])
def clazz(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def api_request(clazz):
    return clazz()

@pytest.mark.parametrize("clazz", [ClassifyRequest], indirect=True)
def test_classification(api_request):
    # do smth
```